# No suitable constructor found for type when we use an Enum - Jackson JSON

Tags: java, json, enums, jackson

I got a class that looks like this:

```
   public class Content {

        public enum Type {
            TEXT, URL, FILE
        }

        public enum Rendering {
            MARKDOWN, HTML, PLAIN, AUTO
        }

        public final Type type;
        public final Rendering rendering;
        public final String content;

        public Content(Type type, Rendering rendering, String content) {
            this.type = type;
            this.rendering = (rendering != null ? rendering : Rendering.AUTO);
            this.content = content;
        }

    }
```

And I got a JSON string that looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "TEXT",
    "rendering": "AUTO",
    "content": "Lorem ipsum"
}
```

Now, because fields in `Content` class is final, Jackson won't work, so I use [MixIns](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations):

```
    public abstract static class ContentMixIn {
        @JsonCreator
        public ContentMixIn(@JsonProperty("type") Type type,
                @JsonProperty("rendering") Rendering rendering,
                @JsonProperty("content") String content) {
        }
    }
```

Note: I could have annotated the original class using the constructor parameters, but `Content` is from a library which I cannot modify

And this is how I use them:

```
    // ... 
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.setMixInAnnotation(Content.class, ContentMixIn.class);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(module);
    mapper.readValue("<the json>", Content.class);
```

This would throw:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.foo.Content]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: {
    "type": "TEXT",
    "rendering": "AUTO",
    "content": "Lorem ipsum"
}; line: 2, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1063)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:124)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3051)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2146)
```

Why? By simpley looking at the line number, I assume It's complaining about the `enum Type`, but how do I correct this?

PS: MixIn is setup correctly because when I replace my Content constructor's enum paramater with String values, it works(although not the way I want it):

```
        // ... in the Content class
        public Content(String type, String rendering, String content) {
            this.type = null;
            this.rendering = null; 
            this.content = content;
        }

        // ... in the mixin class
        @JsonCreator
        public ContentMixIn(@JsonProperty("type") String type,
                            @JsonProperty("rendering") String rendering,
                            @JsonProperty("content") String content) {
        }
```

Comment: What version of Jackson are you using?

Comment: Your example works fine for me with 2.3.0. You also don't need the `@JsonCreator`.

Comment: I switched to the 2.3.0 and the results is exactly the same, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the class is as you are presenting it here?

Comment: In the PS you talk about a constructor with three `String` parameters. Is that maybe the only constructor in the `Content` class?

Comment: Nope, I set that up just to see if MixIn worked at all, and it did work because String worked.　So the problem is about the enums....

Comment: I don't understand. You said you couldn't change the class.

Comment: I recreated the class by looking at the source for testing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67674/discussion-between-tom91136-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer. You may want to either delete your question or update it with the relevant `import` statements. A self answer wouldn't be bad either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, I imported the wrong type because I was using Intellij and didn't pay attention when it asked which type to import.

**When working with Jackson, it is extremely important to pay attention to the types.**

Special thanks to @Sotirios, he gave me various suggestions on this question which helped me a lot on debugging.
It turns out that I  got another class that looks like this:

```
    public static class Image {
        public enum Display {
            COVER, CONTAIN, START, END
        }
        public enum Type {
            BASE64, FILE, URL
        }
        public final Type type; // <-- this!
        public final Display display;
        public final int padding;
        public final String content;

        public Image(Type type, Display display, int padding, String content) {
            this.type = type;
            this.display = display;
            this.padding = padding;
            this.content = content;
        }
    }
```

Jackson failed because I was using `Image.Type` in my MixIn class and `Content.Type` in my actual class. (They looked identical in code because Intellij did a static import)

I also discovered that you should always use `List<T>` for JSON arrays(`[...]`) instead of `T[]`